# Javascript split array into multi array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm having a little trouble with using javascript to split an array into a multi array.  For instance, I have this array:

```
[0] => object
   [0] => object
      [0] => The Letter P
      [1] => 5.5
   [1] => object
      [0] => 5
      [1] => 1.1
      [2] => 5
      [3] => 1
      [4] => 1
   [2] => object
      [0] => 5
      [1] => 1.1.1
      [2] => 1.1.1
      [3] => 1.1.1
      [4] => 3
```

What I would like to do is split up the periods, and create an even deeper array like this:

```
[0] => object
    [0] => object
       [0] => The Letter P
       [1] => object
          [0] => 5
          [1] => 5
    [1] => object
       [0] => 5
       [1] => object
          [0] => 1
          [1] => 1
       [2] => 5
       [3] => 1
       [4] => 1
    [2] => object
       [0] => 5
       [1] => object
          [0] => 1
          [1] => 1
          [2] => 1
       [2] => object
          [0] => 1
          [1] => 1
          [2] => 1
       [3] => object
          [0] => 1
          [1] => 1
          [2] => 1
       [4] => 3
```

I have tried just about everything that I can think of and I can't seem to find a code that works :( Please help me :(

Comment: Are the numbers strings or numbers? Test `if (~~x !== x)` for _Number_ and `x.indexOf('.')` for _String_.

Comment: The code you posted is not (valid) javascript. I don't know all programming languages but I think it's not valid syntax in any language. Since your question is about javascript: could you show javascript code to clarify your question?

Comment: @PaulS.: Is that supposed to do 32-bit-integer-conversion? Just test `typeof x`

Comment: @Bergi It tests if a _Number_ is **not equal** to the integer version of itself. If that is true then the number has some non-integer part to it, so special behaviour.

Comment: @PaulS.: Ah, it was meant as an answer. I suspected it was related to your question regarding the type of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all your replies but I managed to figure it out on my own. It's amazing what happens when you take a break from programming and let your mind go at ease. Anyways, knowing that I have three lays to start within my array, I was able to write the following code:

```
for(a = 0; a < array.length; a++){
  for(var b = 0; b < array[a].length; b++){
    for(var c = 0; c < array[a][b].length; c++){
      if(array[a][b][c].indexOf(".") > 0){
        array[a][b][c] = array[a][b][c].split(".");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At first I tried using while loops, but that required a lot more code and was a lot more confusing. Then I started using the for loop which works a lot better for this type of system. Thanks again for your replies and I hope this helps anyone else who tries to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
function dotsToArr(arr) {
    for(var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        if(typeof(arr[x]) != "object") {
            var parts =  (arr[x]+"").split(".");
            if(parts.length > 1) {
                arr[x] = parts;
            }

            continue;
        }

        dotsToArr(arr[x]);
    }
}
```

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gER22/

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete solution, but I use this function to accomplish something like you're describing.

```
function parseStringToArray(inputString){
    var parts = inputString.split(".");
    var arr = [];
    while (parts.length){
        arr.push(parts.shift());
    }
    return arr;
}
function parseArray(inputArray){
    var arrayLength = inputArray.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        if (inputArray[i].indexOf('.'){
            inputArray[i] = parseStringToArray(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help?

```
var toString = Object.prototype.toString;

function parseArray(obj) {
    var i, l;

    if (toString.call(obj) === "[object Number]") {
        obj += "";
    }

    if (toString.call(obj) === "[object String]" && obj.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
        obj = obj.split(".");
    }

    if (toString.call(obj) === "[object Array]") {
        for (i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            obj[i] = parseArray(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```